# How to not add Notification broadcast in Queue? laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, pusher

what I want to achieve is to broadcast notification immediately instead of need to run

> php artisan queue:listen

If in Event class I just need to Implements ShouldBroadcastNow to make events broadcast immediately. But I tried same things in Notification but it is not working.

Notification

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Tournament;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class TournamentAdded extends Notification implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $tournament;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Tournament $tournament)
    {
        $this->tournament = $tournament;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            $this->tournament
        ];
    }
    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            $this->tournament
        ]);
    }
}
```

Execute notification

```php
 $t = Tournament::latest()->first();
 $user->notify(new AppTournamentAdded($t));
```

Comment: Use a different queue connection using the `synchronous` queue driver, which requires no listening process.  It will block the current request until finished, so make sure it doesn't time out the request.

Comment: @ChuckAdams How do I change queue driver to synchronous? Is it by adding `return (new BroadcastMessage([
            $this->tournament
        ]))->onConnectionn('sync');`

I got error **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage::onConnectionn()**

Comment: It's in queue.php.  You wouldn't change your existing queue connection, just add a new one.  See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Comment: @ChuckAdams Solved it! Thank you So much. I typo at `onConnectionn` change to return `(new BroadcastMessage([ $this->tournament ]))->onConnection('sync');`and it broadcast immediately.